# Is extern class declaration usage C++ standard compliant?

Tags: c++, extern

```
class My_Container
{
    /*...*/
    class iterator
    {
        extern class const_iterator;
        Node* _ptr;
    public:
        bool operator==(const iterator& other) {return _ptr == other._ptr;}
        bool operator==(const const_iterator& other) {return _ptr == other._ptr;}
    };
    class const_iterator
    {
        Node* _ptr;
    public:
        bool operator==(const const_iterator& other) {return _ptr == other._ptr;}
        bool operator==(const iterator& other) {return _ptr == other._ptr;}
    };
}
```

It doesn't compile if I omit `extern class const_iterator;` declaration.
It is C++ 17 standard compliant?
Can an inner class access to private members of another inner class?

Comment: It doesn't compile _with_ the `extern class const_iterator`, but if you (1) declare `const_iterator` before `iterator`'s definition (at class scope) and (2) make `_ptr` `public` and (3) remove `extern class const_iterator`, then it does.

Comment: please add the compilation errer

Comment: Use forward declarations, define members which depend on the exact definition into separate .cpp files unless your container is a template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is extern class declaration usage C++ standard compliant?

No, this is not standard compliant. Classes cannot have a storage class specifier.

> Can an inner class access to private members of another inner class?

Same way as any other class; it can access public members. The example accesses private member outside of the class, and as such it is ill-formed.

> It doesn't compile if I omit extern class const_iterator; declaration.

Use a regular forward declaration instead:

```
class const_iterator;
class iterator
{
   // ...
};
class const_iterator
{
   // ...
};
```

I recommend solving the problem another way: Define `const_iterator` first. Make `iterator` implicitly convertible to `const_iterator`. Make `const_iterator` comparable to only `const_iterator`.

Comment: I did as you said and it works, but your solution also accesses a private member of another class: `iterator(const const_iterator& other) : _ptr(other._ptr) {}`

Comment: @Alexv Provide a public constructor that accepts a pointer, and implement the conversion as an operator calling that constructor. Or use a friend delaration.